# Не запускается python скрипт в systemd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

/etc/systemd/system/sendermail.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Serder mail
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/callbackformserver/sender_mail.py > /var/www/callbackformserver/systemd.log 2>&1
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

В автозапуске ошибка

sudo systemctl status sendermail :

```
● sendermail.service - Serder mail
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sendermail.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-11-09 14:00:14 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 27811 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/callbackformserver/sender_mail.py > /var/www/callbackformserver/systemd.log 2>&1 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 27811 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 09 14:00:14 ip-172-31-32-65 systemd[1]: sendermail.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 09 14:00:14 ip-172-31-32-65 systemd[1]: sendermail.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 09 14:00:14 ip-172-31-32-65 systemd[1]: sendermail.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 09 14:00:14 ip-172-31-32-65 systemd[1]: sendermail.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 09 14:00:14 ip-172-31-32-65 systemd[1]: Stopped Serder mail.
Nov 09 14:00:14 ip-172-31-32-65 systemd[1]: sendermail.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 09 14:00:14 ip-172-31-32-65 systemd[1]: sendermail.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 09 14:00:14 ip-172-31-32-65 systemd[1]: Failed to start Serder mail.
```

Скрипт рабочий (запускал той же командой как в ExecStart). Но почему-то в автозапуске не запускается и никаких логов не остаётся. Что не так настроил?

Comment: Type=idle ? может лучше `simple`

Comment: Type=idle ? может лучше+

Comment: c Type=simple те же ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Мне в похожей ситуации помогло поле Description=Serder_mail без пробелов записать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3` в кавычках: `ExecStart="/usr/bin/python3"`